# Any way to reset Interval value if a certain condition met?

Tags: rxjs

Suppose I have an array of integers and I want to iterate over this array in a interval of one second, the current second being the index of the array. Once the index reaches the end, I want to reset the interval value. Whats the right approach to achieve this behavior?
[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-interval-fpohmm)
Code:

```
const array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

interval(1000)
  .pipe(
    tap(second => {
      if (array[second]) {
        console.log(array[second]);
      } else {
        //reset interval to run in a cyclic manner?
      }
    })
  ).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 2):

So you want to repeat the same sequence indefinatelly.

```
import { from, of } from "rxjs";
import { concatMap, repeat, delay } from "rxjs/operators";

const array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

from(array)
  .pipe(
    concatMap(second => of(second).pipe(
      delay(second * 1000),
    )),
    repeat(),
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-interval-pmlj6e

Comment: Could you please provide some elaboration to this solution? Also, the delay feels longer than one second

Comment: The delay is `value * 1000`. You can leave it to `1000` if you want constant delay. `concatMap` stacks all values emitted by `from` and calls its project function for each of them after the previous one completes. `repeat()` will just resubscribe when the last number is delayed and the source completes.